# Removing first appearance of word from a string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm not familiar with regex, and it would be great if someone giving a solution using regex could explain their syntax so I can apply it to future situations.

I have a string (ie. `'Description: Mary had a little lamb'`), and I would like to remove `'Description: '` such that the string would read `'Mary had a little lamb,'` but only the first instance, such that if the string was `'Description: Description'`, the new string would be `'Description.'`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that the first instance will always be at the start of the string?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Python's [str.replace](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace) has a max replace argument. So, in your case, do this:

```
>>>mystring = "Description: Mary had a little lamb Description: "
>>>print mystring.replace("Description: ","",1)

"Mary had a little lamb Description: "
```

Using regex is basically exactly the same. First, get your regex:

```
"Description: "
```

Since Python is pretty nice about regexes, it's just the string you want to remove in this case. With that, you want to use it in re.sub, which also has a count variable:

```
>>>import re
>>>re.sub("Description: ","",mystring,count=1)
'Mary had a little lamb Description: '
```

Comment: you don't need to specify the third argument as it defaults to 1

Comment: @omu_negru No it doesn't. It defaults to all occurrences.

Comment: @omu_negru It does not default to 1, it defaults to... Nothing I guess. If you don't have the third argument, it will replace all instances, not just the first one.

Comment: Ah, just found out about .replace() a few minutes ago, Thanks! Would still be helpful to know using regex

Comment: @zhuyxn Updated to have a regex solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it without regex, using the replace function by setting the `count` arg to 1:

```
>>> string = 'Description: Mary had a little lamb Description'
>>> string.replace('Description', '', 1)
'Mary had a little lamb Description'
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work for any "word", not just "Description: "

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Blah: words words more words'
>>> print re.sub(r'^\S*\s', '', s)
words words more words
>>>
```

Comment: If you just wanted to remove the first word in a string, wouldn't you just use " ".join(s.split(" ")[1:])?

Comment: @Josiah, better would be `s.partition(" ")[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `regex` just specify the count paramter as `1` in `re.sub`. Although it seems like `regex` is not needed in this case.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Description: Mary had a little lamb'
>>> re.sub('Description: ','',text,1)
'Mary had a little lamb'
```

Comment: Can I ask what the count parameter is doing?

Comment: @song0089 Only 1 substitution